# Is it a problem to use normal HTML elements instead of Ionic elements?

Tags: android, html, ios, angular, ionic-framework

I want to improve ionic app UI design in general but I used HTML tags instead of ionic tags to improve form fields so my question: Will this behavior cause ionic app to perform badly and have compatibility issues in both Android & iOS? If the answer is Yes, can I get the same UI design as in HTML tags image below using ionic tags?

https://ibb.co/9hzDfVM

Using Ionic tags

```
<div class="content">
    <ion-list class="form-list">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'add_users.Email' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="usersData.email_id"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="(usersData.email_id && !email_validation) && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="(!usersData.email_id || email_validation) && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'add_users.Name' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usersData.first_name"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.first_name && !user_name_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.first_name && user_name_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'add_users.user_id' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usersData.username"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.username && !user_id_required && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.username && user_id_required && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'add_users.Password' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="usersData.password"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.password && !password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.password && password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'add_users.confirm_password' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="usersData.confirm_password"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.confirm_password && !confirm_password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.confirm_password && confirm_password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'user_profile.user_type' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-select interface="action-sheet" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="usersData.user_type" [value]="usersData.user_type">
              <ion-select-option value="3">{{'user_profile.Moderator'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="1">{{'user_profile.Admin'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="2">{{'user_profile.Teacher'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="4">{{'user_profile.Parent'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="5">{{'user_profile.Register'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="6">{{'user_profile.Medical'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="7">{{'user_profile.Viewer'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row class="time-row">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-toggle slot="end" color="primary" (onChange)="check()" [(ngModel)]="usersData.attendence_permit"></ion-toggle>         
            <h3>{{'user_profile.edit_permission'| translate}}</h3>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group num-stepper-fn">
              <span class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateVal('down')">
                  <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
              <input type="number" class="my-form__input form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="usersData.time"
                name="qty" id="qty" min="1" max="420" minlength="1" maxlength="420" step="1">
              <span class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateVal('up')">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <span>{{ 'user_profile.note' | translate }}: {{ 'user_profile.input_time_type' | translate }}</span>
        </div>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'teacher_profile.class'| translate}}</ion-label>
            <ionic-selectable style="height: 6vh; margin-top: -2px;overflow: hidden;" 
              [(ngModel)]="usersDataclass"
              [isMultiple]="true"
              [items]="classes"
              itemValueField="cid"
              itemTextField="name"
              (onChange)="portChange($event)"
              [canSearch]="true">
            </ionic-selectable>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
    
    <div class="btn">
        <ion-button expand="block" (click)="submit()"><ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="show_save_user_spinner"></ion-spinner><span *ngIf="!show_save_user_spinner"> {{'add_users.Submit' | translate}} </span></ion-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using HTML tags

```
<div class="content">
    <ion-list class="form-list">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">{{'add_users.Email' | translate}}</label>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="(usersData.email_id && !email_validation) && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="(!usersData.email_id || email_validation) && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="usersData.email_id"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fullname">{{'add_users.Name' | translate}}</label>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.first_name && !user_name_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.first_name && user_name_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" [(ngModel)]="usersData.first_name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">{{'add_users.user_id' | translate}}</label>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.username && !user_id_required && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.username && user_id_required && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="usersData.username"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">{{'add_users.Password' | translate}}</label>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.password && !password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.password && password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="usersData.password"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirm_password">{{'add_users.confirm_password' | translate}}</label>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="usersData.confirm_password && !confirm_password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="valid-input" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!usersData.confirm_password && confirm_password_validation && submitted" slot="end" class="invalid-input" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" [(ngModel)]="usersData.confirm_password"/>
          </div>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'user_profile.user_type' | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-select interface="action-sheet" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="usersData.user_type" [value]="usersData.user_type">
              <ion-select-option value="3">{{'user_profile.Moderator'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="1">{{'user_profile.Admin'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="2">{{'user_profile.Teacher'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="4">{{'user_profile.Parent'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="5">{{'user_profile.Register'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="6">{{'user_profile.Medical'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
              <ion-select-option value="7">{{'user_profile.Viewer'| translate}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row class="time-row">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-toggle slot="end" color="primary" (onChange)="check()" [(ngModel)]="usersData.attendence_permit"></ion-toggle>         
            <h3>{{'user_profile.edit_permission'| translate}}</h3>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group num-stepper-fn">
              <span class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateVal('down')">
                  <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
              <input type="number" class="my-form__input form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="usersData.time"
                name="qty" id="qty" min="1" max="420" minlength="1" maxlength="420" step="1">
              <span class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateVal('up')">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <span>{{ 'user_profile.note' | translate }}: {{ 'user_profile.input_time_type' | translate }}</span>
        </div>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>{{'teacher_profile.class'| translate}}</ion-label>
            <ionic-selectable style="height: 6vh; margin-top: -2px;overflow: hidden;" 
              [(ngModel)]="usersDataclass"
              [isMultiple]="true"
              [items]="classes"
              itemValueField="cid"
              itemTextField="name"
              (onChange)="portChange($event)"
              [canSearch]="true">
            </ionic-selectable>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
    
    <div class="btn">
        <ion-button expand="block" (click)="submit()"><ion-spinner name="crescent" *ngIf="show_save_user_spinner"></ion-spinner><span *ngIf="!show_save_user_spinner"> {{'add_users.Submit' | translate}} </span></ion-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for HTML tags:
https://codepen.io/Fahad-Aldhafeeri/pen/WNaVbeN

Comment: The best way to answer that is to run the app with Ionic tags, measure the performance, then run the app with HTML tags and measure the performance. Compare the two.

Comment: How we can measure this performance. Is there a tool can help with that ?

Comment: Pretty much all browsers come with Developer Tools that include performance measurement. I don't know about Ionic native applications. You're better off asking with the [android] or [ios] tags if you want information specific to those platforms.

Comment: Yes, this is what i would like to know exactly doing things like that will effect app performance in both Android & iOS and how much this will effect so I will asking with the [android] or [ios] tags

Comment: afaik, the iconic components just have styling to help match android or ios, in the end its all html element, since this is hybrid apps. They run through a webview on the mobile phones. So in terms of performance, you probably get a marginal increase of just using html elements. But you lose out on theming from ionic.